# Cannot enter characters in the login page of TopCoder Arena

Tags: java-web-start

I am new to TopCoder and I am quite confused when I want to login the TopCoder Arena.

I have already registered and select that I would like to compete on TopCoder, then when I open the jnlp file I downloaded from the website. It shows me the current login page. However, I cannot type in any characters in the username and password. Other buttons like auto detect work well, but the settings of proxy cannot be edited as well.

Does anyone else meet this problem in the previous experience with TopCoder Arena? Is that a problem caused by java web start or Mac OSX? I have already updated the jre to the latest version, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: This is something you should take up with Top Coder.

Comment: Is the Top Coder login page based on Java webstart? It seems to be plain html when I go to their site, in which case this would a browser problem. If there is a Java webstart login application for TopCoder please give us the link so we can test it.

Comment: @SaeidNourian Thanks for your time. The TopCoder website is just a plain html. However, TopCoder also has an arena for users to compete on it. After login the TopCoder website, you can choose "Algorithm(SRM)" at left side, and there is a link of "Launch Arena".

Comment: it seem to be a bug with update 40 of Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904317/java-8u40-on-os-x-yosemite

Comment: @sasha Dave's answer really works for this problem!

Answer (score 2):

As Saeid Nourian mentions, this is a bug in Java SE 8 u40.

If you want to workaround it for now, you can do this:

- Open Java Control Panel (Apple symbol > System Preferences > Java)
- Go to the Java tab, and click View...
- Find the line for 1.8.0_40 - there is probably only one line
- In the Runtime parameters column, double click to go into text entry mode and type "-Xdebug"
- Click OK and OK again to exit the control panel

If you try to open TopCoder again, you should now be able to enter text.