# Java 8u40 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, java-web-start, osx-yosemite

Since the update of Java 8u40 our OSX users have not been able to type anything into the application and the application also does not even gain focus.  I have tried other Web Start examples and I have the same issue, so it isn’t just us.

I went to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examplesIndex.html and launched both Web Start demo’s on that page.  I can double-click in the fields and it appears it wants to rename or edit text but the caret doesn’t show up and typing doesn’t work.  Also, Finder (or whatever app I had touched last) is still on the Mac title/tool bar. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865399/osx-blocking-jnlp-launch-java1-8u40-anyone-know-why

Comment: The link above says to use -Xnosplash, but that did not work for us.  However -Xdebug does work.  We don't like using it, but for clients that refuse to downgrade to Java 8u31 we are offering that to them as a workaround.  Hopefully Oracle will fix this soon.

Comment: I found a new version of Java [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) that seems to have the problem fixed.

Comment: Yes, we have confirmed that 1.8.0_40-b27 has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the exact same thing with every webstart application I can find (including our own). We got a report from a customer that they could not log in to our application (because the JTextField doesn't get focus), also 8u40 on Yosemite. We have since reproduced it on two other Macs with Yosemite and 8u40. I have reported a bug to Oracle, and have not found any workarounds.

Comment: We reported the bug to Oracle as well.  Haven't heard anything back yet. The run time parameter -Xdebug does work if you are in the same boat as us.

Comment: -Xdebug seems to work on 8u40, but it doesn't work on the early access of 8u60.

Comment: That's disheartening.

Comment: This is a major problem if true (I haven't had the chance to test it yet). Do you guys have a link for your bug reports?

Comment: I don't have a bug id yet, but I will post it when I receive one.

Comment: This is fixed in build 1.8.0_40-b27