# Java JTextField entry broken on 1.8.0_40 OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: java, macos, jtextfield, java-web-start

After upgrading to java 1.8.0_40 from java 1.8.0_31 `JTextFields` are no longer accepting any input.

> Environment OS X 10.2.2 java 1.8.0_40 (the current build). iMac 4 GHz
>   Intel Core i7.

I'm using webstart to launch the apps.

In order to test, I created a simple new project from the code downloaded from here:

> http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jtextfield-class-example

This sample code failed as well.  In fact using the Oracle website examples fails to allow text field entry.

You can test from here:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Assuming you have the same environment.

It does not appear to fail on Windows 7 under Parallels on the same machine, can't say about other environments.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I just used brew cask to update my mac's jdk to 1.8.0_40 oracle 64 bits and the JTextField demo from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java  works fine. Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: It seems to be a new bug introduced in update 40. People already filed a bug report for it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904317/java-8u40-on-os-x-yosemite

Comment: so it's specific to java web start

Comment: Yes same jar run locally works.