# Java JTextField and JTextArea are broken on 1.8.0 OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, jtextfield, jtextarea, text-rendering

I've just faced a general problem with **`JTextField`** in **`Java 8`** on **`OS X 10.10 Yosemite`**:

My particular case: **`JTextField`** with a custom font does not handle/render the text correct.

1. Cursor position is not calculated right
2. Selection bounds are not calculated right
3. In the case that text exceeds `textfield` bounds: text is not scrolled right, selecting and moving a text with the mouse produced heavily distorted display.

Similar effects affect **`JTextArea`** too.

I'm using **`Java 1.8.0_25`** on **`OS X 10.10.2`**, so this is not **`1.8.0_40`** - specific.

A similar problem is described here:
[Java JTextField entry broken on 1.8.0_40 OS X Yosemite 10.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971608/java-jtextfield-entry-broken-on-1-8-0-40-os-x-yosemite-10-10-2)

My custom font is a OTF font Myriad: stored in MyriadPro-Bold.otf, loaded with following code:

```
Font loadFont(GraphicsEnvironment ge, InputStream fontInputStream) throws FontFormatException, IOException
{
    Font toreturn = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontInputStream);
    ge.registerFont(toreturn);
    return toreturn;
}
```

Does anyone know how to work this around? Or if this problem is going to be fixed in the near future?